# How in SQL UPDATE rows with differences only

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables DESTINATION and STAGING with the same structure and very similar data. Only in few rows I've some differences. For example:
In DESTINATION table I have rows:

```
ID, Name, ShortName
1, Name1, N1
2, Name2, N2
3, Name3, N3
```

In STAGING table I have:

```
ID, Name, ShortName
1, Name1, N1
2, Name2, newN2
3, Name3, N3
```

How to update DESTINATION table only 2nd row with new data in ShortName column (newN2) and doing nothing with rows without any differences?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like this

```
  UPDATE A
  SET A.shortname = B.ShortName
  FROM DESTINATION A
       INNER JOIN STAGING B
       ON A.ID=B.ID
  AND A.shortname<>B.ShortName;
```

Comment: This is only na example. I'm looking for solution which update all rows in DESTINATION table where data related with ID will be different in STAGING table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, this is how you can do it:

```
update d
  set ShortName = s.ShortName
from destination d
join staging s
  on d.id = s.id
  and d.ShortName != s.ShortName;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0119c/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using an UPDATE...FROM:

```
UPDATE Destination
SET ShortName = stg.ShortName
FROM Staging stg -- Reference "staging" table
WHERE Destination.ID = stg.ID 
AND Destination.ShortName <> stg.ShortName; -- Only update rows with "ShortName" values don't match
```

This will update your `DESTINATION` table using the data in your `STAGING` table.  This works on Postgres.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad370/1

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL , using merge script is best way of updating table. You can look up on multiple columns.

```
MERGE dbo.Destination AS TARGET
USING dbo.staging AS SOURCE
    ON (TARGET.[id] = SOURCE.[id])
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET TARGET.[shortName] = SOURCE.[shortName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (
            [Id]
            ,[Name]
            ,[shortName]
            )
        VALUES (
            SOURCE.[Id]
            ,SOURCE.[Name]
            ,SOURCE.[shortName]
            )
```